# Can I exclude properties or fields in a base class from being serialized with Mongo DB C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to serialize a class I have and save it to a Mongo database I have. The issue I have is that the class I have inherits from another base class from a 3rd party library (Unity3D). The class is specifically MonoBehaviour.

Example:

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool PreviewEnabled;

    public float Spread { get; set; }

    public float Spacing { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public float Chaos { get; set; }
}
```

So this saves to my DB without issue, however when I try to deserialize and convert it back to an instance of Weapon I get an error from the MongoDB assemblies.

I know this has to do with my base class as if I look at the document in my DB it now has a few extra fields/properties in it that are not in my Weapon class, but I know are a part of the base class, Monobehaviour. Here is an example of one saved document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54dd153596a433238cd3ea42"
    },
    "name": "PlayerPreview",
    "hideFlags": 0,
    "active": true,
    "tag": "Player",
    "enabled": true,
    "useGUILayout": true,
    "PreviewEnabled": true,
    "Spread": 0,
    "Spacing": 1,
    "Count": 2,
    "Chaos": 0,
}
```

So I imagine the error happens because it is trying to map things that exist in a Monobehaviour like `enabled` and `useGUILayout` to non-existent properties in my Weapon class.

**How can I tell MongoDB to ignore fields / properties specifically in this Monobehaviour base class considering the fact that I do not have the source for this class - its in the Unity3D library that I have not got access to?**

Here is the error I get:

```
(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExecutionScope,object,object) <IL 0x00016, 0x0007f>
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize (MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader,System.Type,System.Type,MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializationOptions) <IL 0x00183, 0x00967>
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize (MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader,System.Type,MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializationOptions) <IL 0x0004d, 0x001e7>
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1<Weapon>.ReadFrom (MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBuffer,MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializationOptions) <0x00772>
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage<Weapon> (MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBinaryReaderSettings,MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer,MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializationOptions) <0x0030d>
```

Also to note, I have tested that this all works by saving a normal class with no inheritance of a base class to the DB and deserialized it back into my game with the same logic I am using for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using `ConventionPack` though it might be better to use a different model instead and convert back and forth in this case - after all, you're getting into trouble if the type *changes* in new release...

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true));
ConventionRegistry.Register("sloppy", pack, 
                             t => typeof(MonoBehaviour).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

### EDIT

I didn't read that question carefully, sorry. After all, the values *are* present in your class. The problem is that MongoDB doesn't know the class inheritance, and you can't decorate the base class with `[BsonDisriminator(Required=true)]`.

While you can also do that during runtime, using foreign classes for serialization will be a constant source of pain, especially if they decide to make the class immutable in certain ways. I'd use a separate model and use map back and forth, maybe using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to avoid stupid copy code. (This is the second time I recommended AutoMapper in 5 minutes, but no, I'm not affiliated in any way...)

Comment: Interesting - thanks! I'm a complete newbie with MongoDB so I had to do a bit of reading on all of that.  So I am not quite sure how to map like you are recommending (don't know automapper), but I believe I have done it manually for now - I created a separate class called WeaponMapper (which inherits from MonoBehaviour, and which I can place on my game objects now), gave it the exact same properties I needed to keep in the DB that the normal Weapon class has (I removed the base class inheritance of MonoBehaviour from the Weapon class), and now whenever I store a "Weapon" I map those manually?

Comment: To further my last comment, is what I am doing now essentially what you meant I should try? Mapping properties from my Monobehaviour inheriting WeaponMapper instance to my Weapon instance then saving that to the DB. When I pull the Weapon instance back, I map that back onto the relevant WeaponMapper instance. Could AutoMapper do this for me and ensure that any changes I make to Weapon in the future would get mapped to WeaponMapper or vice-versa?

Comment: Essentially, yes. AutoMapper is convention based (maps equal names) but can also be configured quite a bit. I'd try to generally separate your domain model (which has a dependency on unity) from your persistence layer through these mappings. An alternative is to configure the MongoDB driver to use custom constructors or use custom serializers, but there's a lot of risk that some future change in either library requires you to go to great lengths to fix the constructor calling again (take DI into the equation and you're at three libraries, add some unmanaged code and there's reason to cry...)

Comment: Thanks again for the information - I'll take a look at AutoMapper when I get a chance as it sounds pretty useful!